# Order an ActiveRecord relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord Object called `contact`. It has an relation called `profiles`. These profiles have a url property. The profiles should be ordered by url in alphabetical order. I've tried `sort_by` as well as `order` but I get this error:

```
contact.profiles.sort_by! { |profile| profile.url }
undefined method `sort_by!' for #<Profile::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000105d6d430>
```

What's the best way to do this? I'm using Rails v4.1.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [order query method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) for sorting the profile records based on `url` attribute of `Profile`

```
contact.profiles.order(url: :desc) ## sort in descending order
```

For ascending order you can specify `asc` instead of `desc`.

**UPDATE**

On second note, if you wish to retrieve profile records *always* sorted by `url` then update the `Contact` model as:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :profiles, -> { order url: :desc } ## change order as per your requirement to asc / desc
  # ...
end
```

After this, `contact.profiles` would *always* result in sorted profiles based on `url`.

Comment: When I substitute `sort_by!` form my example with `order!`, the error is gone but the profiles aren't sorted.

Comment: What do you mean by alter the data?  Do you need `contact.profiles` to always return `profiles` records ordered by `url`?

Comment: Read the UPDATE section in the answer. Added an extra note

Comment: Ah yes, the second solution solved it. Thanks a lot! :)